# UWP: ItemMargin not updating to correct value

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing a UWP App which uses a Carousel Control from the Windows Community Sample. I am trying to make the images of the Carousel appear at ItemMargin = actualWidth/2. Also I made this dynamic by using Page.SizeChanged. I am  using the MVVM pattern here. My problem is that when I assign ItemMargin = actualWidth/2 in the ViewModel, it doesn't reflect in the actual View.My code is as follows:

Sample.xaml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  SizeChanged = {onSizeChange}
  x:Name ="Carousel"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

   <Grid>
     <Border Margin="0">
       <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
              InvertPositive="True"
              ItemDepth="300"
              ItemMargin="{x:bind ViewModel.ItemMargin}"
              ItemRotationX="0"
              ItemRotationY="45"
              ItemRotationZ ="0"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              SelectedIndex="4">
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="200"
              Height="200"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
              Stretch="Uniform" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:Carousel>
</Border>
```

Code behind Sample.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class Sample
 {
   //constructor
   public Sample()
   {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.UpdateWidth();
   }

  private void SizeChange(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _ = sender; // reference unreferenced parameter
        _ = e; // reference unreferenced parameter
        this.UpdateWidth();
    }

    private void UpdateWidth
    {
        this.ViewModel.UpdateItemsMargin(this.Carousel.ActualWidth);
    }

   }
```

ViewModel code is as follows SampleViewModel.cs

```
  public class SampleViewModel
 {
    private int itemM;

    public int ItemsMargin
    {
        get => this.itemM;
        set => this.SetProperty(ref this.itemsM, value);
    }
    
    public void UpdateItemsMargin(double actualWidth)
    {
        this.ItemsMargin = (int)actualWidth / 2;
    }


  }
```

I noticed the value of Items Margin in the View not change . However, if I change the value directly in the value i can see the change. In addition , i also used the debugger to see the change if actualWidth has a non null value and it does. Any idea as to why i cant see the change in Items Margin the carousel Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value of `ItemMargin` property to change when the `Page.SizeChanged` event handler is triggered and then the value of `ItemsMargin` in binding source changes, you need to let the `SampleViewModel` implement [InotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) interface which notifies clients that a property value has changed, and apply the `OneWay` mode in **{x:Bind}** extension.

For example:

```
public class SampleViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int itemM;
    public int ItemsMargin
    {
        get { return itemM; }
        set 
        {
            if (itemM != value)
            {
                itemM = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public void UpdateItemsMargin(double actualWidth)
    {
        this.ItemsMargin = (int)actualWidth / 2;
    }
}
```

Apply `Mode=OneWay` in the binding of `ItemMargin` property.

```
ItemMargin="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemsMargin,Mode=OneWay}"
```